# NestJs compiling Angular application while they are in different folders

Tags: angular, nestjs

### Current behavior

When using npm start, it also compile my angular application in my dist folder. This cause this error to appear:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\lecle\Desktop\Workspace\template\rest-api\dist\main'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Structure of application:
A www folder which contains a rest-api folder for NestJs app and a webui folder for Angular

### Expected behavior

Should only compile my nestjs application

### Environment

```
Nest version: 7.1.5
 
For Tooling issues:
- Node version: 13.9.0
- Platform:  Windows


Others:
- Angular version: 9.1.12
```

Comment: what are your package.json scripts? Is there one script for compiling both parts of application?

Comment: Turn out to be a stupid error where I was importing a module from Angular in my NestJs application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was cause by an import from my Angular application. I had the same module in Angular and the import linked to my Angular app.